# Replacing linearity with additivity (Wilansky)

Tags: functional-analysis

Our professor said that (due to Wilansky Thm) if in the following we replace linearity of $L$ with additivity *only*, still the theorem holds, that is for an $L$ such that $L(x_1+x_2)=L(x_1)+L(x_2)$ the following statements are equivalent :

[image]

I have done all implications except for $(b) \implies (d)$. Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$L(x+y)=L(x)+L(y)$ implies that $L(nx)=nL(x)$ for any $n \in \mathbb N$. Replacing $x$ by $\frac x m$ we can see that $L(rx)=rL(x)$ for any positive rational number $r=\frac n m$. In above proof of b) implies d) you only have to let $\epsilon \to 0$ along a sequence of numbers such that $\frac {\delta} {\|h\|+\epsilon}$ remains rational.

[You can take $\epsilon_n =\frac {n\delta} {[\frac {n\delta} {\|h\|}]}-\|h\|$ (if this is not $0$ and $\epsilon =\frac 1n$ if it is $0$ where $[x]$ is the greatest integer not exceding $x$].